# Node.js/Express.js Chain Certificate Not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, express, ssl-certificate

I have an SSL server in Express, which is not working on all browsers (unless the user manually trusts the website) since some browsers require the chain certificate (we have our own intermediate certificate). I've put our intermediate and chain certificate in one .crt file. The chain + intermediate certificate is in the `INT_CERT_FILE` variable. It does not seem to work. I am using http://www.digicert.com/help, as well as running `openssl s_client -connect tasker.adnxs.net:443 -showcerts | grep "^ "` to check, but it does not seem to be returning the intermediate + chain certificate.

Here's how I'm setting it up:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var https = require("https");
var express = require("express");

var KEY_FILE = fs.readFileSync("path/to/key/file.key");
var CERT_FILE = fs.readFileSync("path/to/crt/file.crt");
var INT_CERT_FILE = fs.readFileSync("path/to/intermediate and chain crt.crt");

var _app_https = express();
var _server_https = null;

_server_https = https.createServer({
    key: KEY_FILE,
    cert: CERT_FILE,
    ca: INT_CERT_FILE
}, _app_https).listen(443);
```

When visiting it on Firefox, Firefox does not recognise its identity and requires it to be manually trusted. How can I fix this issue?

Thanks,

Comment: I used .toString() after the readFileSync(...)

Comment: Still does not work. http://www.digicert.com/help/ says no certificates found.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Does your intermediate certificate file contains multiple certificate blocks?

If that's the case you should split them into different files and read them one by one. You can pass them as an array to the `ca` parameter.

I've got it working with the code below:

```js
var https = require('https'),
    read = require('fs').readFileSync,
    httpsOptions = {
        key: read('ssl/mycertificate.key', 'utf8'),
        cert: read('ssl/mycertificate.crt', 'utf8'),
        ca: [
            read('ssl/rapidssl_1.pem', 'utf8'),
            read('ssl/rapidssl_2.pem', 'utf8')
        ]
    };

https.createServer(httpsOptions, function (req, res) {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: This actually works?  The nodejs docs say that the `ca` option is used for authorizing connections and it seems as if it should do nothing unless the `requestCert` and `rejectUnauthorized` options are turned on.  https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v0.10.x/api/tls.html#tls_tls_createserver_options_secureconnectionlistener

Comment: My issue was to do with nginx and [this link](https://cheapsslsecurity.com/blog/install-ssl-certificate-nginx-http-server/) resolved it for me.

Comment: dunno why its only work on chrome, in mozila doesnt work .#edit its work bro btw i use your code without ca properties thanks you saved my life

Answer (score 9):

Handy little snippet if you actually can't modify any SSL-related files on the server - you can split the "ssl chain" file yourself. Spent a little while when tried to get Node and socket.io to work with SSL (was getting net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE error on the client) so thought will share it:

```js
var read = require('fs').readFileSync;
var privateKey = read(MY_KEY_LOCATION, 'utf8');
var certificate = read(MY_CERT_LOCATION, 'utf8');
var chainLines = read(MY_CHAIN_LOCATION, 'utf8').split("\n");
var cert = [];
var ca = [];
chainLines.forEach(function(line) {
  cert.push(line);
  if (line.match(/-END CERTIFICATE-/)) {
    ca.push(cert.join("\n"));
    cert = [];
  }
});
var credentials = {
  "key": privateKey,
  "cert": certificate,
  "ca": ca
};
var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(httpsServer);
```