# Loading an intermediate Certificate to Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, express, ssl-certificate

I am trying to get my intermediate cert to be recognized by node.js.
I am on a windows server 2008R2 and IIS 7 for the main application
 However I have an application on port 4443 that is node.js and needs to be served via https. I have the pfx file that I am pointing to in the ssloptions and passing that into the createserver along with the passphrase.
The intermediate cert has been installed into the windows certificate store .
I am using this middleware https://github.com/coolaj86/node-ssl-root-cas
He

Here is my code:

```
    var myssl = require('ssl-root-cas/latest').inject()
.addFile('path-to-app/ssl/gd-g2_iis_intermediates.pem');

…
var ssloptions = {

   pfx: fs.readFileSync('path-to-app/ssl/my.pfx'),
   passphrase: "thecorrectpassword"
};


app.listen = function(){
  //var server = http.createServer(this);
  var server = https.createServer(ssloptions,this);
  return server.listen.apply(server, arguments);
};
```

When I test the url https://example.com/ at the SSL checker  it reports the chain as complete. when I check this url  https://example.com:4443/  I get the message

> The certificate is not trusted in all web browsers. You may need to install an Intermediate/chain certificate to link it to a trusted root certificate. Learn more about this error. You can fix this by following GoDaddy's Certificate Installation Instructions for your server platform. Pay attention to the parts about Intermediate certificates.

The GoDaddy docs are no help.

Any and all help very much appreciated.

Thanks

Mark

Comment: Does this similar question help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19104215/node-js-express-js-chain-certificate-not-working

Comment: Just to make sure: Seems like the variable `myssl` is not relevant to this question, as it's not used for anything in the code? Also, where do you get the error message you pasted? The error message refers to GoDaddy documentation, so surely this is not a message you get from the browser itself, but somewhere else?

Comment: thanks for your help @Lesley, The question you reference is for a key and .cer cert, I am using a pfx which is mutually exclusive from using the ca array as outlined in the question you reference,

Comment: @AugustLilleaas - I go to SSL checker [link]https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html  and put in my URL with the 4443 pport and get that message back. Thanks